# URL Rewrite in htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Am rather new to this world of htaccess redirects.Am trying to force all redirects in my Zend MVC to my https but I get a *requested URL* not found error on requests that dont go though the index controller

Example

```
https://www.example.com/auth/register
```

gives a ***requested URL /auth/register*** not found error. However if I remove the https redirect rule it works fine over http. If I adjust the URL to

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/auth/register
```

it works fine.
The URL

```
https://www.example.com/index/faq
```

works just fine since it goes through the index controller.

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

What do I need to adjust to get the URL

```
https://www.example.com/auth/register
```

working?

Comment: Found my problem.I didnt specify the mod-rewrite rule for SSL requests via port 443.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads as "If this matches a file, link, or directory, then do nothing and continue."  You need to skip the final rewrite rule in the case the file actually exists:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=1,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```